# How to calculate effect of different variables/parameters on a quantity?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, computer-science, game-theory, scoring-algorithm

I am developing a game for iOS. In the game I have around eight different parameters that directly affect the score of the player. We can say that these eight variables decide the difficulty of the game and hence score. Is there any way that I can combine these variables to produce a combined affect on the score. I have seen Elo's method for chess games but that is not useful for me.I welcome any mathematical method to attain the desired results.

Comment: The partial derivatives of the score function with respect to each variable should give you some idea

Comment: @danimal Do you have some idea of a game using that approach. I'll be able to connect better.

Comment: no idea, sorry! do you have a score function?

Comment: @danimal Right now I just have variables/parameters. And I want to be very fair with players while scoring them. I guess there is some way to achieve exactly this.

Comment: Let's say the eight variables are $x_1,x_2,..,x_8$. Since we want each parameter  to have a different weightage in the score, we could set the total score as score=$w_1x_1+w_2x_2+...+w_8x_8 \over w_1+w_2+...+w_8 $ where $w_i$ represents the weightage we give to the ith parameter while calculating the total score.

Comment: @SrinivasK Yeah that looks good but I'm still skeptical about the approach. Actually these variables are deviations from their last value that can be positive or negative.